# Writing a list to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For a school assignment I need to make a poll with ASP.NET
The problem I get when trying to write the answers in the database is that only one question and one answer gets written into it.

This is the View

```
 @model CinemaJamV2.WebUIV2.Models.EnqueteModel
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Enquete";
 }

<h2>Enquete</h2>

 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Enquete", "Enquete", new { vraag = "vraag", antwoord =      "antwoord", naam = "naam", cijfer = "cijfer" }))
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @for(var i=0;i< Model.enquetevragen.Count();i++)
        {
            <div class="thumbnail">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.enquetevragen[i].vraag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.enquete.antwoord, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.enquete.cijfer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        }
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Naam <input type="text" name="naam" /> </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzend" />
    </div>
 }
```

This is the Controller:

```
namespace CinemaJamV2.WebUIV2.Controllers
{
    public class EnqueteController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository<Enquete> repository;
        private IRepository<EnqueteVraag> a_repository;
        private CineJamContext db = new CineJamContext();

        public EnqueteController(IRepository<Enquete> a_model, IRepository<EnqueteVraag> vraag_model)
        {
            repository = a_model;
            a_repository = vraag_model;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Enquete()
        {
            EnqueteModel enquetevragen = new EnqueteModel
            {
                enquetevragen = a_repository.List
            };
            return View(enquetevragen);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Enquete(Enquete enquete)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Enquetes.Add(enquete);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Enquete");
            }

            return View(enquete);
        }
    }
}
```

The ModelView:

```
namespace CinemaJamV2.WebUIV2.Models
{
    public class EnqueteModel
    {
        public List<Enquete> enquetes {get; set;}
        public Enquete enquete { get; set; }
        public List<EnqueteVraag> enquetevragen { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is the Model Enquete which should contain all the given answers:

```
namespace CinemaJamV2.Domain.Entities
{
    [Table("Enquete")]
    public partial class Enquete : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string vraag { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        //[Required]
        public string antwoord { get; set; }

        public int? cijfer {get; set;}

        [StringLength(50)]
        //[Required]
        public string naam { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This Model contains all the Questions

```
namespace CinemaJamV2.Domain.Entities
{
    [Table("EnqueteVraag")]
    public partial class EnqueteVraag : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string vraag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The action for `POST` has only one instance of the Model as its parameter. You need to read this: [Model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to use view model that will have list of Enquete and then in post method again you need to do for loop and save it to database.

See following links for samples.

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b1e0b153-47f4-4b29-8583-958aa22d9284.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET